# Building swift package for iOS specifically using Github actions

Tags: swift, continuous-integration, uikit, github-actions, swift-package-manager

I have swift package for iOS apps (it needs `UIKit` to run). I wan't to build this package using Github action this is how my workflow looks like

```
name: Swift

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: macos-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - uses: YOCKOW/Action-setup-swift@master
      with:
        swift-version: '5.3'
    - name: Build
      run: swift build -v
    - name: Run tests
      run: swift test -v
```

When I run this build I got `error: no such module 'UIKit'`.

So I have 2 options:

1. make my package UIKit independent (actually don't know how)
2. configure build to run on iOS specifically

What should I do?

Comment: Even though the swift commands may be running on the ‘latest macOS’ that doesn’t necessarily mean that `UIKit` is available. One of the easiest ways to work around this is to use compiler `#if canImport(UIKit) #endif` statements around your `UIKit` code.

Answer (score 2):

We're using `xcodebuild` instead of `swift build` to do platform specific CI from GitHub Actions. See specific example at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/master/.github/workflows/spm.yml and https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/master/scripts/build.sh#L540

Answer (score 2):

The simplest approach as of 2022 is to use `xcodebuild` like stated above.

Condensed to the basics, the script can be as simple as this:

```yaml
# This workflow will build a Swift project
# For more information see: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/automating-builds-and-tests/building-and-testing-swift

name: Build and Test

on:
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "main" ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: macos-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    # Sanity check to make sure we use a valid device in the next step
    - name: List available devices
      run: xcrun simctl list devicetypes 
    #generic/platform=iOS is sufficient for just building, - but need to specify concrete destination for tests
    - name: Build and run tests
      run: xcodebuild test -scheme YourSchemeNameHere -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 13 Pro' #or any other name from the list of sim devices
```

This is enough to build the project and run tests on it.

In some cases you may need to install a later version of Swift than what's available by default on Github Actions, - you can use a third party step for that and use `xcode-select`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the GitHub actions needed when you want to run tests on a Swift Package.

I added the iOS version as the package uses SwiftUI code.

Just add the `Xcode.app` name found on your MacBook, as well as the `simulator name` and `iOS version` associated.

```yaml
name: NAME_OF_YOUR_CHOICE

on:
  pull_request:
    branches: ["main", "develop"]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: macos-latest

    name: Unit Testing on iOS 16.2

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Select Xcode
      run: sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app && /usr/bin/xcodebuild -version
    - name: Build and run tests
      run: xcodebuild test -scheme YOUR_PACKAGE_TARGET_NAME -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 14 Pro,OS=16.2' | xcpretty && exit ${PIPESTATUS[0]}
```